# Email client that supports Gmail in 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gmail

I tried to use my Gmail account with Thunderbird and it does not work in 20.04. Can some help me find a trusted email client which allows the use of Gmail in 20.04 ?

I am not sure about the tech details. My aim is to receive emails and if possible send as well.

Comment: Does "*it does not work*" mean that you have already tired https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thunderbird-and-gmail ?

Comment: Most any email client should work. Use IMAP w/server imap.googlemail.com on port 993.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Mailspring](https://getmailspring.com). It's fast, modern, and works with most email services (including Gmail).